# Can I use fprintf within a rcpp-sourced C++ function?

Tags: r, rcpp

I have some code I found online that I would like to use in a R project. I managed to compile and call everything with

```
libary(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("rcpp/my_function.cpp")
my_function("testdata.dat", "testout.dat", opt_verbose = 1)
```

In the function are several fprintf calls, e.g.

```
fprintf(stderr, "Error: minvotes < 0!\n%s", usage);
```

However they don't print to the R console. Is there a way to see the output of `fprintf` when using the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

a) This works fine in a standard R session in any standard terminal:

```
> Rcpp::cppFunction("void printDemo() { fprintf(stderr, \"hello, world\\n\"); }")
> printDemo()
hello, world
>
```

and please note the fact that I had to escape quotes and backslash for use with `cppFunction()`.  So if this doesn't work for you *you have an issue with your terminal/display*.  Which did you use?

b) But you are not supposed to use it -- and *Writing R Extensions* is very clear about this.

c) Which is why we mostly use the *wrapper* `Rcpp::Rcout` and `Rcpp::Rcerr` which redirect into R's own buffered input/output as required by *Writing R Extensions*.

Comment: Thank, Sir Eddelbuettel. It is amazing that across all Rcpp question you manage to quickly answer :) I now replaced `fprintf(stderr, "...%s", usage)` with `Rcpp:Rcerr << "..." << usage`. Before I was using Rstudio and fprintf showed nowhere in terminal/display.

Comment: You're welcome, and strange. I wouldn't think RStudio blocks stderr.  And the above example works for me (Ubuntu 20.10, R 4.0.4, RStudio 1.4.1641).  Oh well.  And just for completeness, R has at the C level also has `Rprintf()` and `REprintf()` -- see _Writing R Extensions_.

Comment: actually I now noticed that all output to stderr / stdout is buffered (and withheld), but printed as soon as I source the file again. Running `sourceCpp("my_function.cpp")`  seems to "flush" all the output to the console.